# New to Python - Making a GPA calculator

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to python and trying to figure out how to add in a function to some programming I did already.  I wrote  (below) a bit to convert the letter grade to GPA (Grade Point Average) and want to change it so I can type in several letters and get an averaged GPA.  What I'm having trouble with is how to get it to run each input letter and then convert it into a new form; I'm thinking I have to use a "for gp in range:" sort of thing, but am pretty lost on how to start.  Any ideas?

```
from sys import argv
def gp(w):
if w.startswith("A"):
    gp= int(4)
if w.startswith("B"):
    gp= int(3)
if w.startswith("C"):
    gp= int(2)
if w.startswith("D"):
    gp= int(1)  
if w.startswith("F"):
    gp= int(0)
if w.endswith("+"):
    return gp+0.3
if w.endswith("-"):
    return gp-0.3
else:
    return gp
if __name__ == '__main__':
grade = argv[1]
print("%.1f" % gp(grade))
```

Comment: Look up Python dict: `{'A':4, 'B':3, 'C':2, 'D':1, 'F':0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def gp(ltr):
    grade = {"A":4.0, "B":3.0, "C":2.0, "D":1.0, "F":0.0}
    mod   = {"": 0.0, "+":0.3, "-":-0.3}
    return grade[ltr[0]] + mod[ltr[1:]]

letters = "B A A- C F A"
grades  = [gp(letter) for letter in letters.split()]
average = sum(grades) / len(grades)
```